# Filter by list of tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, functional-programming

What is the concise, functionally-oriented way of filtering a list of URLs where each item has to pass a list of tests? If the URL matches *any* of the tests, it should be filtered out.

I currently have:

```
var _ = require("underscore");

const anchors = [
    {href:"https://example.org/contact"},
    {href:"https://example.org/faq"},
    {href:"https://example.org/contact"},
    {href:"https://example.org/uploads/image-1024x1018.jpg"},
    {href:"https://example.org/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=example"},
    {href:"https://example.org/author/pm"},
    {href:"https://example.org/wp/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword"},
    {href:"https://example.org/wp/wp-login.php"},
    {href:"https://example.org/feed"},
];

const tests = [
    /\/wp\//,
    /\/wp-json\//,
    /\.jpg$/,
    /\.png$/,
    /\.gif$/,
]

function testAll(testString){
    let pass = true;
    _.each(tests, t => {
        if(t.test(testString)) pass = false;
    });
    return pass;
}

console.log(anchors.map(anchor => {
    return anchor.href;
}).filter(anchor => {
    return testAll(anchor);
}));
```

But I suspect `testAll` can be done in a more concise way.

Comment: `Array.prototype.every`

Comment: You can always do `tests.every(t => t.test(stringHere));` `every` returns `true` only if *every* element in the array returns `true` - so your function just becomes: `let anchorsPass = anchors.every(a => tests.every(t => t.test(a.href));`

Comment: what is `/$.png/` doing? `$` is the end of the string sign.

Comment: @NinaScholz Mistake—fixed with edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I was looking for is actually `some` instead of `every`, because I actually need to reject the URL if it matches *any* of the tests:

```
console.log(anchors.map(anchor => {
    return anchor.href;
}).filter(anchor => {
    // return testAll(anchor);
    return !_.some(tests, t => {
        return t.test(anchor);
    })
}));
```

Comment: You can probably omit the entire `map` call as well - just `.filter(anchor => {
    // return testAll(anchor);
    return !_.some(tests, t => {
        return t.test(anchor.href);
    })
})`

Comment: And you can also probably use the `some` function that's built into `Array` instead of using underscore.js (`tests.some(t => t.test(anchor.href))`)

Comment: `map`-then-`filter` causes multiple iterations thru the same collection – you can use `anchors.filter(({href}) => tests.every(t => !t.test(href)))` or use `Array.prototype.reduce` if you want to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
function testAll(testString){
    return tests.every(reg => reg.test(testString));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could work with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and take the negated result of the checks for filtering.

```js
var anchors = [{ href:"https://example.org/contact" }, { href:"https://example.org/faq" }, { href:"https://example.org/contact" }, { href:"https://example.org/uploads/image-1024x1018.jpg" }, { href:"https://example.org/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=example" }, { href:"https://example.org/author/pm" }, { href:"https://example.org/wp/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword" }, { href:"https://example.org/wp/wp-login.php" }, { href:"https://example.org/feed" }],
    tests = [/\/wp\//, /\/wp-json\//, /\.jpg$/, /\.png$/, /\.gif$/],
    result = anchors.filter(({ href }) => !tests.some(t => t.test(href)));

console.log(result);
```